# How do I parse site html with "span"?

Tags: python, html, parsing

I'am new in web-parsing and I ran into a problem.
I wanna extract number of watching from the site:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqrXF.png)

I wrote this code for that purpose:

```
url = 'https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/4638344'
request = requests.get(url)
req = request.text
soup=BeautifulSoup(req, 'html')
abcd = soup.find("div", class_="doc_sharing__body js-social").find("span", class_="sharing")
print(abcd)
```

But result of this query is "None"

What's the problem? Please, help!

I try many iterations with different variation of my code (for example):

```
url = 'https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/4638344'
request = requests.get(url)
req = request.text
soup=BeautifulSoup(req, 'html')
abcd =  soup.find_all("span", attr = {'class':'sharing'}
print(abcd)
```

But I have same result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view count is stored in the `data-article-views=` parameter:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/4638344'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for article in soup.select('article[data-article-views]'):
    print(article['data-article-title'], article['data-article-views'])
```

Prints:

```
«Газпром» начал поставлять газ в Сербию по «Турецкому потоку» 14541
```

Comment: Thank you very match!
You're absolutely right!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that something like this script can help you retrieve the number of views (I am assuming that this number is the one inside the title tag):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/4638344"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

sharing_div = soup.find("div", class_="doc_sharing__body")

title = sharing_div.find("span", class_="sharing")["title"]

watching_number = title.split(": ")[1]

print(watching_number)
```

Note: Maybe you'll have to use `.find_all()`, instead of `.find()`. In this case, you have to inspect the retrieved results, to check which of them contains the desired title tag.

Comment: Unfortunately, It's not working(
The problem is that variable "sharing_div" dosen't consist information about watching number:
[<div class="doc_sharing__body js-social" data-social-type="article-mobile"></div>, <div class="doc_sharing__body js-social" data-social-type="article-desktop"></div>]

And on the next line we meet the error - function "find" can't find expression "span" and anothers